# Dom string doesn't change after manipulation with jQuery attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, epub

I'm making a js-based epub reader as a weekend project and I'm trying to change the src attribute of the images on each of the book's pages from image urls to data URI's loaded from the epub zip. Here's my function:

```
//page contents is just an html string of the book's page
pageContents = GlobalZipLoader.load('epub.zip://' + pageLocation);
pageContents = replaceImages(pageContents)

...

function replaceImages(pageContents){
  $(pageContents).find('img').each(function(){
    var domImage = $(this);

    //this is something like ".../Images/img.jpg"
    var imageLocation = domImage.attr('src'); 

    //this returns the proper data-uri representation of the image
    var dataUri = GlobalZipLoader.loadImage('epub.zip://' + imageLocation);

    //this doesn't seem to "stick"
    domImage.attr('src', dataUri);
  });
  return pageContents;
}
```

The returned pageContents from the replaceImages functions still has the old src attributes. I can provide more detail if needed but any help would be very much appreciated.

Correct answer thanks to The System Restart and Ilia G:

```
function replaceImages(pageContents) {
    newContent = $(pageContent);
    ... manip ...
    return newContent;
}
```

Comment: `pageContents` is a cached item, you probably need to refresh it before returning it.

Comment: It does seem like there's some weird caching stuff going on, how might I refresh the pageContents before I send it back?

Comment: Oh I see the new comments... I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to change the image `src` after image load complete;

and I think this is happening with in `loadImage` function.

According to your update question:

You don't need any `clone()`, I think. Just store `pageContents` in a `tempContents` variable and use that variable

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, so there's no way to change it before that dom string is appended to my page? If I have to wait until after it's fine but it generates a ton of 404's and I'd like to avoid that if necessary. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to clone it. Simply set `pageContents = $(pageContents);`, then perform your image replacement on `pageContents`, then `return pageContents.html();`

Answer (score 1):

Since pageContents is just a string, you'll need to return the modified version of it. Try this:

```
function replaceImages(pageContents){
  // save jQuery object
  var $pageContents = $(pageContents);

  $pageContents.find('img').each(function(){
    var domImage = $(this);

    //this is something like ".../Images/img.jpg"
    var imageLocation = domImage.attr('src'); 

    //this returns the proper data-uri representation of the image
    var dataUri = GlobalZipLoader.loadImage('epub.zip://' + imageLocation);

    //this doesn't seem to "stick"
    domImage.attr('src', dataUri);
  });

  // return contents of the modified jQuery object
  return $pageContents.html();
}
```